# Amp Page Script and hashtag navigation

Tags: amp-html

Adding the script https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js disables hashtag, on-page page navigation. Any issues like that I've missed?

Comment: Works for me. Got an example or any more details?

Comment: I just tried it and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/vgxg2h6d/

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Your example doesn't seem to work in Firefox. In Chrome, the second link does not work (though it seems to be set up right).